# Easypost - Updating 'OPTIONS' after creating Shipment and before buying label

Tags: fedex, easypost

I am using Easypost and creating the shipment by passing `from_address, to_address, parcel, customs_info, carrier_accounts, options`. The shipment got created successfully.

And at the time of buying the label(of this shipment), I would like to include more `options`. Is there any possible way to update the `options` at the time of buying the label?

Codebase: **Nodejs**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the EasyPost API once a shipment object is created there isn't a way to modify the options on the shipment. What you'll need to do instead is create a new shipment with the options set the way you'd like. Since you haven't bought the shipment yet it won't cost you any extra either.

You can always email their support team (support at easypost dot com)

Comment: I emailed them around 4 days back and still not response at all.